# How to add data to an XML file without causing infinite loop

Tags: c#, xml, linq

I have an XML file that looks like below:
I am attempting to add new book but as apparent, I get stuck into an infinite loop. How can I do this without re-evaluating books from the query. It appears I am appending the file then re-evaluating causing the issue. 
I attempting a `for loop` with iteration but no desire result.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<item>
   <book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   </book>
</item>

<item>
   <book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   </book>
</item>
</catalog>
```

I need to add a book into both item nodes so that each item will have a total of two books based on the author.

**The result will look like this:**

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<catalog>
<item>
   <book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>XML Developer's Guide</title>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>C# Developer's Guide</title>
   </book>
</item>

<item>
   <book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>Midnight Rain</title>
   </book>
   <book>
      <author>Ralls, Kim</author>
      <title>C# Developer's Guide</title>
   </book>
</item>
</catalog>
```

Code:

```
        XElement root = XElement.Load(@"C:\source\catalog.xml");
        IEnumerable<XElement> books =
        from el in root.Descendants("book")
       where el.Element("author").Value == "Ralls, Kim"

        select el;

        foreach (XElement el in books)
        {
            el.AddAfterSelf
            (
            new XElement
            (
                "book", new XElement("author", "Ralls, Kim"),
                        new XElement("title", "C# Developer's Guide")
            )

            );

            Console.WriteLine(el.Value);
        }

        root.Save(@"C:\dest\catalog.xml");
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Updating your code to:

```
List<XElement> books =
    (from el in root.Descendants("book")
    where el.Element("author").Value == "Ralls, Kim"
    select el).ToList();
```

should do the trick if I'm reading this right.

The important part is the `ToList()` it causes the linq query to only evaluate once and use that initial result for all the later use cases.

Comment: You are correct, I did think about using `ToList()` but did not think it would work. Thank you. This solves the problem.